# Fail to connect to generic netlink under WSL

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a new user of Ubuntu.  I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 on my PC using WSL (Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store), and it's running OK.

And I've installed Wireshark (Version 3.2.3 (Git v3.2.3 packaged as 3.2.3-1) ) into the WSL Ubuntu platform.

But when I start Wireshark, I have this screen:

```
gerard@DESKTOP-BUREAU:~$ wireshark
QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/myfile/, 0 instead of 1000
Failed to connect to generic netlink.
17:51:37.849     Main Warn QXcbConnection: XCB error: 147 (Unknown), sequence: 178, resource id: 0, major code: 141 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

I've looked for a solution for a long time, but I still haven't been able to resolve it.  I just don't understand the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `sudo wireshark`, or run `wireshark` from the application menu that's brought up by hitting the "Windows" key.

Comment: Thank you heynnema but this action gives nothing, same problem.

Comment: Uninstall the old git version, and install the newer version from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: heynnema, i have the git version 2.25.1

Comment: How is this related to the version numbers indicated in your question. In all cases, you don't have the most current version installed... hence my comment to uninstall and install the version from the Ubuntu repos. What is the URL that you got your version from?

Comment: I used the server VcXsvr for launched the application wireshark  can you give me the list of commands i must do for dowload new version git and install it  thank you

Comment: AFTER uninstalling your version of Wireshark, do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install wireshark`.

Comment: This ubuntu goes from microsoft store  it have the functionnalities: Ubuntu,bash,ssh,git,apt,dpkg.

Comment: Are you talking about WSL? If so, I can't help. Also add that info to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's the same always : Failed to connect to generic netlink. libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast and libGL error: no matching fbconfigs or visuals found   Main Warn QXcbConnection: XCB error: 147 (unknown)78, ressource id: 0 major code: 141 (unknown) minor code: 20

Comment: You didn't answer my question... is this WSL under Windows?

Comment: Yes my ubuntu is a application Windows Subsystem for Linux .  thank you heynnema for your help. I thing que wireshark cannot launched with a WSL. see you later

Comment: you agree with me ?

Comment: I don't know WSL... but yes... wireshark may not work there.

Comment: Hello is somebody know if the application wireshark can be work with Ubuntu WSL ?